# How to trigger a click event function of another component in angularjs4

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-click, angular-components

In my angularjs project, I am facing an issue with click from the html. My code module is as follows
I have a header module and an auth module

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'layout-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
constructor() {}

}
```

In header.component.html I have added a click event, my intention is to call a function from other component
click code is as follow

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" (click)="clickLogout($event)" routerLinkActive="active"> Logout </a> </li>
</ul>
```

"clickLogout" function is added on other component any if does'nt calling up
If I add the same "clickLogout" in header.component.ts, it works.

But for some reason I need it on another component, So is there any option to trigger click of other component from view : (click)="clickLogout($event)"

I am using angularjs4, Somebody please advice!

Directory structure is as follows

```
app 
--auth 
----auth-logout.component.ts 
--shared 
----layout 
-------header.component.ts 
-------header.component.html
```

I need the click call on auth-logout.component.ts

Comment: from which component you want to call it ? Is there any parent child relationship with those 2 controllers? or are they just siblings ?

Comment: No parent child relation, just a sibling. I need click from header component template to call another component function which has no relation with header component

Comment: I have added the directory structure too

Comment: please refer below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Need a shared service to do so :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    logout() {
        this.subject.next({ text: 'logout'});
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
       return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

and in header component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService} from 'service/MessageService'; //import service here as per your directory
@Component({
    selector: 'layout-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
   constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}
    clickLogout(): void {
    // send message to subscribers via observable subject
    this.messageService.logout();
  }
}
```

And in any other component **EDIT**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'; //Edit
import { MessageService} from 'service/MessageService'; //import service here as per your directory
@Component({
        selector: 'another-component',
        templateUrl: './another.component.html'
    })
    export class AnotherComponent {
       constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    // subscribe to home component messages
            this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { 
               //do your logout stuff here
          });
        }

      ngOnDestroy() {
         // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

    }
```

Reference taken from [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject).

Comment: When I click logoutbutton clickLogout() in header component called up successfully => then  logout function of MessageService  called up successfully  => but finally this.logoutService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { }); in AnotherComponent  didnt called up

Comment: add console.log inside  subscribe... does it printed the something ? actually once logout method get fired; subscribe method will automatically get called.

Comment: I am assuming another component  will be in view correct ?

Comment: have u imported logout service in another component ? any error on console ?

Comment: click is from header component template, another component doest have any view and console.log inside subscribe... doesnt print

Comment: @Ajith ok... i am asking whether another component is already rendered on browser irrespective of it has any view or not ? imported your logoutService ?

Comment: My another component is nowhere used, May be that is the problem

Comment: thats problem..u atleast need to render another..may be empty component in view(having no HTML). 

Also I wonder it that component is not in use then whats point of calling logout method from header component to another component ?

Comment: I made an alternate solution other than this, Anyways this is a new information for me , could try this next time , Thank you :)

Comment: @Ajith ok..so i guess u should post your answer here and accept it  to close the thread